# 5V@5A switching power supply shuts down after few seconds

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a Meanwell 5V@5A switching power supply, and when I try to power anything it shuts down after few seconds. What is more "it sings" I guess that the coil saturates, which migh be caused by too low output impedance, but that can't be the case cause I am plugging in multiple devices.

On Meanwell site it says in FAQ that this beahaviour can be caused by either Short Circuit (checked), Overvoltage protection or overtemperature protection. SPS is not hot at all during the start and I've set the output voltage to exactly 5V.

The SPS shuts down always at the same moment - when the bootloader loads the linux kernel.

EDIT: The answer to this question is: the cables from the SPS were too long and there was a 1V voltage drop on each of them.

Comment: Fixed it myself. The voltage drop was too low during the kernel load, just had to trim the output voltage to 5.5V and everything works! Should I delete this question?

Comment: I think you are going to have problems with this in the future. At the very least, if this is part of a design and not a single system, you should diagnose further. How much current are you drawing? What is the max current? What is the min current? Data or a link to the power-supply would be helpful.

Comment: I am using RS-25-5 Meanwell Switching power supply. Aproximate current draw is ~20A (8 devices each needs approx 500-600mA). I guess the problem is with the SPS. I didn't have time to diagnose it with osciloscope so I don't know the numbers but it shouldn't have such a high voltage drop to cause my device to reset.

Comment: @zdun8 If you find the ultimate cause and solution, please post it as an answer to your own question. That way it can help future visitors which have the same or similar problem.

Comment: This will not account for the power-supply shutting down; but if you have boards that are resetting, it may be that your power wires are too small causing a voltage drop resulting in low-voltage at your boards. Check the supply voltage at your boards. You may need to lower the AWG of your supply wires (fatter wires). In regards to the supply shutting down, take careful notice of your MAXIMUM current draw. You may need a heftier supply.

Comment: Thanks, @Tut. I am using quite long cables (1.5m) and there is a 1V (!?) drop at the board from the sps, which is causing the device to reset, I'll just shorten the wires and it should be fine. I am marking Tut's comment as an answer to this question.

Comment: I assume "Aproximate current draw is ~20A" is a typo. "8 devices each needs approx 500-600mA" totals to 4 to 4.8A

Comment: I have an issue where I have a meanwell `MDR-20-12` powering a GSM modem, and the RF noise from the antenna causes the PSU to switch off. If i cycle the power, it starts working again.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you have already found the cause, which was that you had long cables from the power supply to the load, which caused excessive voltage drop whent the load started drawing significant power.  You have worked around the problem, but not really fixed it.

Shorter cables is a good idea, but just cranking up the voltage so that you still get the minimum at the load under maximum current conditions is not a good solution.  That could possibly cause over-voltage at other times.  The real problem is that the voltage is being regulated at the power supply, not at the load which is at the other end of the cables.

Look at your power supply more closely.  It probably has sense inputs.  These are for exactly your case.  A separate wire is used to feed the actual voltage at the load back to the power supply, and sometimes the same with the ground.  These wires are only signals and carry little current, so don't have any significant voltage drop accross them.  They tell the supply what the voltage is *where you actually want the voltage regulated*, as apposed to what it is at the supply.  The supply then adjusts its ouput (within some limits) to be whatever is needed to produce the correct voltage at the load.

Comment: Good advice regarding the sense inputs, however the OP's power-supply apparently does not include this feature.

Comment: @Tut: That's hard to say since the OP provided no link to a datasheet, not even the exact model.  In any case, getting a supply with sense lines and then using them appropriately is the right way to compensate for long cables.  Of course it's best not to have long cables in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the datasheet for your power-supply: [Mean Well RS-25 Series Datasheet](http://www.meanwell.com/search/rs-25/default.htm)

1) Regarding the power-supply shutting down: You indicated in your comments "(8 devices each needs approx 500-600mA)". You should pay careful attention to your MAXIMUM current draw. With the currents indicated, there is not much margin. You may need a heftier supply.

2) If you have boards that are resetting, it may be that your power wires are too small causing a voltage drop resulting in low-voltage at your boards. Check the supply voltage at your boards. This measurement should include both V+ and DC-common connections at the board being measured. You may need to lower the AWG of your supply wires (fatter wires). As you indicated, shorter wires may also solve the problem; but you should still consider heavier wires as a one volt drop is pretty excessive.

Olin offers good advice regarding sense inputs (which you don't have); however this would not reduce the 1 volt drop you are seeing. With voltage sensing, the power-supply would boost the voltage output requiring more power and you are already pushing the supply too close to it's limits. Regardless of whether voltage sensing is used or not, your supply wires should be sized appropriately.

There are many locations on the web providing guides for selecting proper wire gauge. [PowerStream](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) provides a chart listing ohms-per-1000ft and ohms-per-km, as well as a useful "Voltage Drop Calculator by Gerald Newton".

Also note that sometimes you can get significant voltage drops through connectors. You did not mention the architecture of the system; but if for example you have a card-cage, there may be multiple connections each resulting in some amount of voltage drop. Sometimes there are power connectors on card-cages, power-supplies, etc. that provide multiple pins to handle the full rated current of the device as the individual connections may not be rated for the full current. If you have anything like this, it can be a good idea to use all of the connections provided. I see your power-supply only has one terminal-block connection for V+ and V- so they are probably rated to handle the full 5A. If you have a card-cage, make sure all of the card edges (gold fingers) are clean. It can also be helpful to use contact cleaner on the edge-card connectors.